# Class methods undefined with Node + ES6 + Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to run an express app in ES6. I'm using the following workflow:

1. Transpile ES6 to ES5 using the following gulp task (with `"es2015"` and `"stage-0"` presets in .babelrc):

   ```
   import gulp from 'gulp';
   import gulpBabel from 'gulp-babel';
   import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';

   gulp.task('babel', () => {
       gulp.src([
               'someClass.js',
               'app.js'
           ], {base: './', dot: false})
           .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
           .pipe(gulpBabel())
           .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
   });
   ```

   Which seems to be working fine.
2. Run `node dist/app.js`.
3. The following code is in `someClass.js`:

   ```
   export default class SomeClass {

       someMethod() {
           return 1 + 1;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally, the following code is in `app.js`:

   ```
   import SomeClass from './someClass';

   //express config

   console.log(SomeClass);
   console.log(SomeClass.someMethod);
   ```

Which logs:

```
[Function: SomeClass]
undefined
```

Here is the relevant transpiled code:

**dist/app.js**

```
var _someClass = require('./someClass');

var _someClass2 = _interopRequireDefault(_someClass);

console.log(_someClass2.default);
console.log(_someClass2.default.someMethod);
```

**dist/someClass.js**

```
var SomeClass = function () {
    function SomeClass() {
        _classCallCheck(this, SomeClass);
    }

    _createClass(SomeClass, [{
        key: "someMethod",
        value: function someMethod() {
            return 1 + 1;
        }
    }]);

    return SomeClass;
}();

exports.default = SomeClass;
```

*Why is `someMethod` undefined?*

Comment: `console.log(SomeClass.someMethod());` You have to call the method to get it's value.

Comment: I'm actually trying to pass it as a callback function, so I don't want it called immediately. Even if I do, though, I get `_someClass2.default.someMethod is not a function`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `someMethod` is a instance method. You need to instantiate the class with `new` to use the method.

```
const something = new SomeClass();
something.someMethod();
```

If you want to use the method without instantiating the class, you can define it as a static method.

```
export default class SomeClass {

    static someMethod() {
        return 1 + 1;
    }
}

SomeClass.someMethod();
```

In the comment above, you said that you want to use it as a callback. To use it as a callback, you may want to bind a context to the method if you use `this` keyword in the method. Otherwise, the `this` keyword doesn't point to the instance when it's called as a callback function.

```
var something = new SomeClass();
element.addEventListener('click', something.someMethod.bind(something));
// or
element.addEventListener('click', (event) => something.someMethod(event));
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Very simple mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! I added a note on using a method as a callback function.